# Quadratic Equation Calculation in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, equation

I wrote a small app for the calculation of Quadratic Equations. It works and I can calculate (nearly) every equation that doesnt have a non real discriminant but when I change the value of A to anythinh other than 1, the program gives me weird answers. This is the computation code:

```
- (double)calculateRoot1{
    return (-B + sqrt((B*B)-4*A*C))/2*A;
}

- (double)calculateRoot2{
    return (-B - sqrt((B*B)-4*A*C))/2*A;
}
```

Yet this seems to work with any equation where A=1. I hope you guys can help me out!!

Thanks :)

Comment: Your denominator should be `/(2*A)`

Comment: Or `/2/A`. Also, use `2.0` instead of `2`.

Comment: @rmaddy I've never been completely clear on the modern (llvm?) rules around literal conversion.  Because the lhs `(-B + sqrt((B*B)-4*A*C))` would likely be an double, wouldn't 2 become a double?

Comment: @BrianNickel Most likely. Since `sqrt` should return a `double`, everything else should get converted to `double`.

Comment: thanks yall thats one of those brainfarts that just hurt :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your denominator should be `/(2*A)`. Right now you are dividing by 2 and then multiplying by `A`

This is because the `*` and `/` operators are evaluated left-to-right in C.